# Does Ridley Scott foreshadow a revelation early in Prometheus?

Tags: alien-franchise, prometheus, foreshadowing

Early in the movie *Prometheus*, we see the ship traveling through space with wording being displayed on top of it.

[image: opening text (mission log)]

As you can see, the crew count is displayed as 17.

During the briefing after the crew has been awakened at its destination, we see this collection minus the ship's captain and Vickers.

[image: Prometheus ship crew]

From my count, we seem to be a few members​ short of the aforementioned 17. It seems that at least 3 members may be missing from this group shot. Additionally, if we take David (an android) out, we are now at four members not displayed. So as I originally asked, does Ridley Scott tell us that there are more people on board, because in later events, we do find out differently?

Comment: What?! Another Prometheus letdown I guess.

Comment: Oh right, I got it - camera crew...

Comment: +1 I think Chris is asking if this was a clue for people paying attention. I'd say yes. This number (unbeknownst to most crew) includes Weyland, but **I** sure didn't catch it from that early "reveal" of the passengers. *NICE OBSERVATION!*

Comment: The two missing crew members are holding the camera and the microphone -- but wait, what? Distance from Earth 3.27x10^14km? In other words, they've travelled 10 light years in 2 years with a ship incapable of travelling faster than light?

Comment: I like the contrast of everyone slouching while David sits upright.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here it is, [the Crew of *USCSS Prometheus*](https://avp.wikia.com/wiki/USCSS_Prometheus):

> 1. Janek - Captain (killed in ship's crash)
> 2. Meredith Vickers - Mission director (crushed by the Juggernaut ship)
> 3. Dr. Elizabeth Shaw - Lead scientist (alive as of 2094)
> 4. Dr. Charlie Holloway - Lead scientist (incinerated by Vickers)
> 5. Millburn - Biologist (choked by Hammerpede)
> 6. Fifield - Geologist (incinerated by Janek)
> 7. Ford - Medic (killed by last Engineer)
> 8. Chance - First assistant pilot (killed in ship's crash)
> 9. Ravel - Second assistant pilot (killed in ship's crash)
> 10. Jackson - Mercenary (killed by last Engineer)
> 11. Vladimir - Mercenary (killed by mutated Fifield)
> 12. Taplow - Mercenary (killed by mutated Fifield)
> 13. Sheppard - Mercenary (MIA, last seen driving off on to the surface
>        of LV-223)
> 14. Wallace - Mechanic (killed by mutated Fifield)
> 15. Barnes - Mechanic (killed by mutated Fifield)
> 16. Mechanic 3 -Mechanic (killed by mutated Fifield)
> 17. Peter Weyland - Mission sponsor (killed by last Engineer)

The droids:

> 18. David 8 - Mission attendant (active as of 2094)
> 19. 2 Security Androids - do not count as part of crew (presumably
>             destroyed in ship's crash)

We can see here that David and the two Security Androids are not counted in as human crew members.

Comment: I think you missed the point of his question in regards to it being a "reveal."

Comment: Security droids? Where were they? I don't remember any droids.

Comment: @eidylon If I remember correctly, they're seen briefly by the hangar door in the scene when Fifield gets cooked with the flamethrower.